# copy mysql table from one database on server1 to another database on server2

Tags: mysql, database, copy, warnings

I am trying to copy a table "table1" from "db1" on "server1" to "db1" on "server2". Here is what I attempted:

```
mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD --single-transaction db1 table1 \ | mysql --host=SERVER1 -u USER -pPASSWORD db1 table1;
```

My username and password on both servers are the same. Database name and table name on both servers are same.

But this returns the warnings:

Warning: Using unique option prefix database instead of databases is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
Warning: mysqldump: ignoring option '--databases' due to invalid value ''
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "table1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked:

```
mysqldump -u USER -pPASSWORD --single-transaction --add-drop-table db1 table1 | mysql --host=SERVER1 -u USER -pPASSWORD db1
```

I shouldn't have specified the table name in the end and use add-drop table after single-transaction!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

mysqldump -u -p db_name table_name > table_name.sql

Now take this table_name.sql file to server2, create a database (db_name), exit from mysql command line and use the following command:

mysql -p -u db_name < table_name.sql